# GitHub push path and tags filters confusion

Tags: github-actions

Can someone please point out that I'm doing wrong here?  If I push a file `.github/workflows/esp32_push.yml`, neither of the workflow filters below trigger but if I push a new tag, **both** of them trigger!

```yaml
# In workflow 1
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - '.github/workflows/esp32*'
      - 'actions/espressif/**'
      - 'esp32/**'
    tags:
      - '*'

# In workflow 2
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - '.github/workflows/tlsr825x*'
      - 'actions/telink/**'
      - 'tlsr825x/**'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things happening here, both documented in the GitHub docs, if you know where to find them!

1. `Path` rules are ignored when a `tag` is pushed so to stop `workflow 2` from running when `tags` are pushed, you need to add a `tag-ignore: ['*']` rule
2. `Path` rules are ignored except for the `main`/`master` branch unless you explicitly indicate which branches you want to act on them so you need to add a `branches: ['**']` rule to make the `path` rules apply to all branches.

Thanks to others who responded so a similar question that explained this all!